Is Berkleian Idealism a Paralogism?
I've been trying to understand Kant's rejection of Berkleian idealism.  In addition to his "Refutation of Idealism" in the Critique of Pure Reason, which seems to stress the importance of an inner/outer distinction in order to understand the world and acquire knowledge, there seems to be a more oblique criticism in the Antinomies section of the Critique.
In the first two Antinomies--1) the world has an absolute beginning or is infinite and 2) matter is either infinitely divisible or consists of a fundamental indivisible component--Kant states that both sides of the argument (skeptics on one side and dogmatists on the other) commit a logical fallacy in applying concepts meant for empirical application to ideas that are beyond such application.
Berkeley is not explicitly mentioned in that section, nor is radical idealism, but I feel like, in some sense Berkley, commits a similar fallacy in speaking of the outer world as being mere appearance or mere affects of the mind stimulated by God.  Obviously Kant would say Berkeley is overstepping in making knowledge claims about God, but is there some other logical fallacy being committed here?

I suppose one could draw a paralogism from the pair idealism/realism, but it wouldn't be a simple argument for each of the pair; rather, for each of idealism and realism there are several arguments showing how the idea doesn't work out very well.

Kant's project is quite complex.
According to Kant, the Paralogisms of reason are the metaphysical arguments about the soul. Kant "deconstructs" four fallacious arguments concerning the soul, due especially to Descartes and the rationalists.
The first three arguments conclude that the soul is a substance, is simple,
and is numerically identical through time. In the A edition the Fourth
Paralogism concerns Descartes’s view that knowledge of the mind is
prior to knowledge of spatial objects.
It can be useful Ian Proops, Kant’s First Paralogism (2010):

Kant pursues a variety of projects in the “Dialectic” of the CRP; but chief among them is the program of “transcendental criticism”: pure reason’s systematic detection, correction, and explanation of its own excesses. These excesses occur, according to Kant, because reason constantly strives to transcend the bounds of sense in its pursuit of speculative knowledge. In Kant’s view, all such attempts to “rise above the world of sense through the mere might of speculation” (A 591/B 619)
are destined to fail.


It is a simple matter to describe what the arguments grouped under the
heading of “The Paralogisms of Pure Reason” are supposed to have in common: they are, one and all, supposed to be sophistical categorical syllogisms (A 405–6/B 432–33), whose status as sophistical stems from their being “false” due to their “form” (A 341/B 399).

The Refutation of idealism - where the "dogmatic idealism" of Berkeley is briefly discussed - was added to the second edition (B) of CRP. In the same edition Kant revised the fourth paralogism.
See C.T. Powell, Kant's Fourth Paralogism (1988): "The Fourth Paralogism in A is
more or less clearly directed toward refuting the thesis that we cannot be
sure of the existence of the external world, and this task is shifted in B to the Refutation of Idealism."
